# Why did some nominees for the 2024 Solana Stack Exchange Moderator Election disappear?

Tags: bug, support, election

Several nominees for the moderator election disappeared as the nomination phase turned into the election. One example, from memory is https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/98/beeman.

Why was each nominee removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not going too much into specifics...

- one of the candidates withdrew their own nomination.
- another candidate was removed for not meeting [our minimum age requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357377/208518), as per their profile.

The latter of these was, indeed, a somewhat last-minute removal, because I failed to notice the user's profile before it was pointed out to me. I apologize for the confusion this may have caused.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. One reason why nominees might be removed, is if they have had a suspension that ended within the last 365 days. I noticed that [two users have been suspended](https://solana.meta.stackexchange.com/q/54/61). How many nominations were deleted?

Also, maybe they removed themselves voluntarily when they noticed who the other candidates were (I've seen this happen before, in fact I removed myself from the Operations Research election when I saw that [Professor Paul Rubin](https://rubin.msu.domains/), who also had the highest rep on the entire site by a large margin, had nominated himself).

Finally, you have tagged this question as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), but if users were removed by the CM team, then I think that [support](/questions/tagged/support) would be the way to get their attention. I think that "bugs" are problems with the site that developers (not CMs) would fix, whereas this is less likely to be a bug and more likely to be a matter of users voluntarily removing their nominations or CMs removing them intentionally.

Comment: Very upsetting, but I had the list of nominees in a browser tab that I hadn't refreshed, but I closed it. I'm almost positive that 1 hour before the election started, there were more than the 2 candidates that made it to the election, but I'll never know for sure.